# Use variable value in AT command string?

Tags: c, variables, at-command

I'm working on pic interfacing with GSM/GPRS module. Since I work around with GSM/GPRS, I've to use AT commands. Here I'm working on a protocol called HTTP. I'm needing to pass a variable in an AT commands.

Here is AT command code:

```
SendComd_Resp("AT+QHTTPPOST=22,25,10\r","CONNECT",5000);
```

From the above AT command "22" represent length of payload.

```
py_dt=strlen("here is payload data");
```

I just want to pass py_dt in that AT command instead "22". Like below...

```
SendAtCommand_Response("AT+QHTTPPOST=py_dt,25,10\r","CONNECT",5000);
```

How to pass that variable? I'm using C language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want:

```
char msg[128] = {0};
char* payload = "here is payload data";
int payloadSize = strlen(payload);

// replaces %d with the payload size: 22, or 25, or other value)
sprintf(msg, "AT+QHTTPPOST=%d,25,10\r", payloadSize);

SendComd_Resp(msg, "CONNECT",5000);  // actually send the formatted message
```